# Data in the List gets modified after changing the object in another List

Tags: java, list, arraylist

After adding the object into my list I am changing the data in the list it is getting modified I have the code like

```
List<Data> oldList = // initializing the list
List<Data> newList = // initializing the list

for (Data data: oldList) {
    if (condition) {
        data.setvalue("");
        newList.add(data);
        data.setAnother();
    }
}
```

If I am doing like this, the data object in the `newList` also is getting changed.

I have a requirement that it should be changed in the `oldList` but it should **not change** the data in the `newList`.

Comment: Please provide the actual code, not an approximation. You probably just set `newList` to `oldList` or have a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the objects in the `newList` get affected while changing the object from the `oldList`, then need to create a copy of each object that should be added to the `newList`.

For that, you can implement a [*copy-constructor*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-constructor) (a constructor that expects an object of the same type as an argument) in the `Data` class or make it implement `Clonable` interface (but this approach has some serious pitfalls [*see here - paragraph "Copy Constructor versus Cloning"*](https://www.artima.com/articles/josh-bloch-on-design#part13)).

Assuming that you've implemented a *copy-constructor*, your code might be written like this:

```
List<Data> oldList = // initializing the list
List<Data> newList = // initializing the list
    
for (Data data: oldList) {
    if (condition) {
        Data copyForNewList = new Data(data); // creating a copy of the data object
        copyForNewList.setvalue("");          // changing the copy
        newList.add(copyForNewList);          // string the copy
        data.setAnother();                    // mutating the original object
    }
}
```

Comment: The copy-constructor is the right way to go in this case and copy over all attributes manually. This is the safest way to go with.

Comment: i have an requirement like to change some data in the new list as well as the old list but it should not affect my new list data when i am changing the data in the new list

Comment: @RaghavendraR.V As I've said you have to create a **copy** of the `Data` object instead of placing the same reference into the `newList` have a look at the code snippet provided in the answer and check the related to the *copy-constructor*.